# can't require 'graylog2_exceptions' in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, graylog2

I have a sinatra app which runs on

`ruby 1.9.3-p327with gemset exampleGemset` (.rvmrc file)

when I run

`bundle exec gem list`

I get the gem

`friendlyfashion-graylog2_exceptions (1.3.2)`

but when I try to require it with `require 'graylog2_exceptions'` I get this error

`LoadError: cannot load such file -- graylog2_exceptions`

any ideas??

Comment: If you're using Bundler, then to find out which gems you have installed for the project use `bundle list`. See http://gembundler.com/v1.3/man/bundle.1.html.

Comment: Have you tried the original graylog2_exceptions gem? https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2_exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was resloved by using the gem `graylog2_exceptions` 
simply `gem install graylog2_exceptions` did the trick